# What would cause an RPM drop and engine cutoff after starting a Cessna 152?

Tags: general-aviation, piston-engine, cessna-152

My flight school's Cessna 152 is 30 years old. After refueling, the engine RPM went down and down. I tried putting full throttle in but it just stopped. Was it air in the fuel line or something more serious?

Comment: We really don't have enough information to even make a guess here. "Air in the fuel line" seems unlikely however given my (admittedly limited) knowledge of the Cessna 152's gravity-fed fuel system (absent running the tanks dry or the fuel being shut off). Does the flight school's maintenance team have any ideas?

Comment: There is only one correct answer.  You must assume that is was something serious and have the mechanics check it out. Only they are qualified to determine the cause.

Comment: Happened just once? Perhaps the fuel was contaminated

Comment: Two separate events: engine slowing down and engine stalling.  If you are pushing in the throttle too quickly the engine will stall.  Depending on exact year, it is likely that your plane's engine does not have an accelerator pump.  Result: aggressively moving the throttle in will cause a lean condition and the engine will stall.  Dunno about the slowing down part...

Comment: I've had this a couple of times... when I forgot to push the mixture forward. :P

Comment: Well maintenance said theres nothing wrong with it, fuel was checked and re checked and there was no problem. The RPM after start dropped down and down, till I pushed the throttle full in and out to keep it going. It just stopped. Thanks for the advice thou. I'll be flying in a different 152, that one always has engine problems, especially problems with the starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradual power loss would not be caused by "air in the fuel lines".

The most likely cause is blocked vents. There are pipes that allow air into the tanks so the fuel will flow out. If they are blocked for any reason, fuel will stop flowing, often in a gradual manner.

Another possibility is that there is corrosion or sediment which is blocking the fuel line. Are you checking drain valves on every preflight and after refueling?

Comment: It seems a bit odd for blocked vents to cause the problem at ground idle, but  I suppose it's possible (and seems at least *plausible*). It's actually an easy theory to check if it happens again: Open a tank cap and listen for a "whoosh" of air rushing into the tank to fill the vacuum.